# Excel IRR formula in javasript

Tags: javascript, irr

```
public static async IRRCalc(CArray: string | any[], guest: number) {    
        const inc = 0.000001;
        let NPV;
        do {
          guest += inc;
          NPV = 0;
          for (let j = 0; j < CArray.length; j++) {
            NPV += CArray[j] / Math.pow(1 + guest, j);
          }
        } while (NPV > 0);
        console.log('2222222222');
        return guest * 100;
      }
```

i am using below function IRR calculation by passing my cashflow and guess value 0.001 .i am not getting exact output as my excel is calculated
my excel IRR formula is =IRR(G$26:G$386,0.01)*12

my cashflow input is [-150000,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,659.75,1009.75]}

```
the excel output is 2.36,but why my code is giving 2.336.
can anyone suggest please?
```

so i have tried changing the floting point numbers like gess value to
IRRCalc(IRRval, 0.001)

//to

IRRCalc(IRRval, 0.0001)

inc = 0.000001;

//to

inc = 0.00000001
and followed the example from [Javascript IRR (Internal rate of return) Formula Accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15089151/javascript-irr-internal-rate-of-return-formula-accuracy)  but no solutions i found to make my output same as exell

Comment: Did you check whether the value in Excel is rounded in any way?

Comment: Please do not remove the most important part of your post - the question itself

Comment: sry now the question looks okay

Comment: no ita not rounded formula in excel is =IRR(G$26:G$386,0.01)*12

Comment: What did you try to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: i am trying to call this function   const final = (await this.IRRCalc(repaymentArray, 0.001)) * 12;  and tried with adjusting the floating values to 0.001 and inc values also but not getting appropriate as excel output

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: added .kindly look at once

Comment: Still, what have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: added  please have  a look now